Analytic continuation of a bi-holomorphic automorphism on an irreducible bounded symmetric domain
I need your help.
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a type $IV_n$ Cartan domain, i.e;
$\Omega$ =$\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n$: $1-2Q(z,\bar z)+|Q(z, z)|^2>0,\qquad Q(z, \bar z)<1 \}$
where  $Q(z,w)= \sum_{i=1}^n z_i w_i$.
It is known that any bi-holomorphic automorphism $\phi \in Aut(\Omega)$ is extend continuously to a neighbourhood of $\overline \Omega$.
It is known that any bi-holomorphic automorphism of unit ball $B_n = \{z=(z_1, \cdots z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n: \sum_i |z_i|^2 < 1\} $ $\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ can be extend analytically to a neighbourhood of $\overline B_n$. Also, it is known that Cartan domains are unit ball in some Banach space.
So my question is : Can we  extend $\phi$ analytically on a neighbourhood of $\overline \Omega$ ?
Any type of references or answer will be a great help to me. Thanks!
